# How to get the current value of a QComboBox with a model with two columns?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox, qt5.5

I have a `QComboBox` with a `QSqlQueryModel` as its model. The model is constructed from a database with 
`SELECT type_id, type FROM types` where `type_id` is `int` and type is a `varchar`.

I set the `QComboBox` visible column with the `setModelColumn(1)` function, to see the actual types, instead of the indexes, but when a value is selected, I need to retrieve the `type_id` and I don't know how to achieve that. I can't use here the `currentIndex()` function, because the current index of the `QComboBox` is useless for me.

I think the correct function is the `currentData()`, but I can't figure it out, how to get the data from the first column...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another "solution". I came up with the following workaround: First I set the visible column to `0`, retrieve the `type_id`, then set back the visible column to `1`.

```
ui->comboType->setModelColumn(0);
int type_id = ui->comboType->currentText().toInt();
ui->comboType->setModelColumn(1);
```

I don't know how correct is to do this way, but it works.

**EDIT:**
Finally, I found the solution. I just needed to modify a bit *king_nak*-s answer. Thank you *king_nak*!

```
int row = myComboBox->currentIndex();
QModelIndex idx = myComboBox->model()->index(row, 0); // first column
QVariant data = myComboBox->model()->data(idx);
int type_id = data.toInt();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `currentIndex()` method.
Even if the index does not make sense for your application, it is the row in the underlying model. You can use it to query the data from there

Try this:

```
int row = myComboBox->currentIndex();
QModelIndex idx = myComboBox->rootModelIndex().child(row, 0); // first column
QVariant data = myComboBox->model()->data(idx);
int type_id = data.toInt();
```

Comment: I wanted to use your snippet, but it don't work. The `data` contains an invalid `QVariant` and the `type_id` is always `0`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another pretty way of getting the `id` and that is using `QSqlRecord`.

If we have the model (i.e. `mymodel`) for the combobox, we can get the `QSqlRecord` for the selected row and then the fields we need for that record.

Example:

```
QSqlRecord r = mymodel->record(myComboBox->currentIndex());
int type_id = r.value("type_id").toInt();
```